# Entity Framework Dynamic Include for Generic Type Set Not Working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I Have the following method that expects `string[] include` parameter to include dynamic sub sets of the entity:

```cs
 public virtual CEntity GetByID(int id, string[] include = null)
 {
     // for testing
     include = new string[] { "TypeEntity" };

     using (var _context = new CodeGenerator.Data.AppContext())
     {
         TEntity dbEntity = default;

         if (include != null)
         {

             var query = _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();

             //problem here >

             for (int i = 0; i < include.Length; i++)
             {
                 query.Include(include[i]);
             }

             // debugging the sql statement > it didn't add any include statements, just selec statement
             // expected      dbEntity.TypeEntity != null
             // actual result dbEntity.TypeEntity = null

             dbEntity = query.Where(e => e.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
         }
         else
         {
             dbEntity = _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
         }

         if (dbEntity == null)
         {
             return null;
         }

         return _mapper.Map<CEntity>(dbEntity);
     }
 }
```

My Entity `ProjectEntityProperty`

```cs
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
public class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

 public class ProjectEntityProperty : Entity
 {
     public int EntityId { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; } = "string";

     public int? TypeEntityId { get; set; }
     public int Order { get; set; } = 0;

     public bool IsNullable { get; set; } = false;
     public bool IsPrimary { get; set; } = false;

     public ProjectEntity TypeEntity { get; set; }
     public ProjectEntity Entity { get; set; }
 }
```

The include statement doesn't include the item's subset which is `TypeEntity` , but this code worked:

```cs
 return _context.ProjectEntityProperties.AsNoTracking()
                                .Include("TypeEntity")
                                .Where(k => k.EntityId == entityId)
                                .ToList()
                                .Select(_mapper.Map<ProjectEntityProperty>)
                                .ToList();
```

Is there something wrong with my function `GetByID`?

Comment: I think you're missing to reassign `query` variable. Try something like this 
`  for (int i = 0; i < include.Length; i++)
             {
               query =  query.Include(include[i]);
             }
`

Comment: @MoeJallaq Thank you, that was the problem!

Comment: Glad to hear that!